# Saving a report to a file on a client PC?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms, oraclereports

I would be grateful for a quick sanity check!

When calling Oracle Reports 10g from Oracle Forms 10g, is it possible to run an Oracle Report and save it on the users PC to a specified directory? (I know that if an Oracle Report is run in such a format as PDF the user can save the report to x location). To call the Oracle report I am using the Oracle Forms built-in "Run_Report_Object".

I don't think it is (but would be happy to revise my opinion!) and to obtain such functionality I would have to implement something similar to what is discussed in this [thread](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=4371017&#4371017)

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp: Thanks for adding the oracle reports tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have amended my question to include the fact that I am using the Oracle Forms built-in "Run Report Object" to call Oracle Reports.

There is a Oracle Report parameter: DESTYPE which can accept a value called LOCALFILE which saves the output to the client machine using the file name specified by DESNAME, however as I'm using "Run_Report_Object" it is not possible to use the value LOCALFILE.

One solution is to follow the steps given  [here.](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=1156161#1156161)

**Sources:** Oracle Reports 10g Help (look for DESTYPE), 
          [OTN thread](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=1156161#1156161)

Comment: I'd say WebUtil will be the best way to go.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp If you could provide an answer using WebUtil it'll be greatly appreciated mate ;-)

Comment: That comment was from 8 years ago, and I haven't done forms/reports work for a long time. If I did, I'd start here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/forms/webutil-090641.html